# regex a period in zsh

Tags: regex, zsh

I am trying to find out if a hostname has a domain suffix by searching for a period in the string. I can do it in `bash` with the following

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ "$1" =~ \. ]]; then
  host="$1"
  echo "keep as $host"
else
  host="$1.mydomain.biz"
  echo "change to $host"
fi
```

but it doesn't work for `zsh`. The `[[ "$1" =~ \. ]]` always evaluates to True:

```
#!/bin/zsh
if [[ "$1" =~ \. ]]; then
  # always evaluates to True in zsh
  host="$1"
  echo "keep as $host"
else
  host="$1.mydomain.biz"
  echo "change to $host"
fi
```

Eventually something like this will go in my `.zshrc`, but experimenting with it as a shell file gave me insight.

How should I update the regex evaluation to get this to work in `zsh`? Or is there a different test I can use to determine if I need to add the domain suffix?

My environment is macOS Sonoma 14.2.1, zsh 5.9 (x86_64-apple-darwin23.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There fix is that you need to double escape the dot here:

```bash
if [[ "$1" =~ \\. ]]; then
```

Then the backslash will be treated as a regular, literal backslash that escapes a dot in the regex pattern.

Else, you may simply  use

```bash
if [[ "$1" == *.* ]]; then
```

where `*` stands for any text (it is required because `==` requires an exact match, full string match), but that is no longer a regex.

Comment: Thank you! Both those options work for me. I was trying quotes and removing the backslash and surrounding with parenthesis, but nothing worked. There is no 'zsh' mode in regexr.com, either. While I like the cleverness of using regex, I think I'm going to use the string match because it is clearer in code. If only I had stepped away from the tree to see the forest...